# Can't find System.Windows.Input.Mouse in C# windows form application

Tags: c#

I'm following this tutorial [cursor tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742195.aspx) , but when i copy +paste the code in my c# desktop application and on building the app follwoing error is given

> error CS0103: The name 'Mouse' does not exist in the current context

any idea on this error? I've search for the class "Mouse" and it is there in C# [Mouse Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.aspx)

Comment: Perhaps you can post code and if this is WPF or WinForms...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned System.Windows.Input namespace is part of Windows Presentation Foundation, not Windows Forms.
Maybe you started with the wrong Visual Studio Project template?

Answer (score 3):

Are u sure u did the following :

1: In the soulution explorer added the reference PresentationCore.dll (Under the tab COM)

2: Added "using System.Windows.Input;" at the top of the current file

Answer (score 1):

There's a Mouse class in `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices` as well - I suspect they copied and pasted that bit of their code from their VB example on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in WinForms you can implement the same logic using the `Cursor.Current` instead of WPF-specific `Mouse.OverrideCursor`.

Links:

- [Cursor.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.current.aspx)
- [Mouse.OverrideCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.overridecursor.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted to the tutorial shows a WPF application, not a winforms.